# Django: Combining field error message

Tags: python, django

I have created a custom django user account creation system that uses an email [using this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). I would like to combine the error message that says "this field is required" for both email and password into one error message that says "email and password fields cannot be left blank"

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit `UserCreationForm` from `forms.Form` instead of `forms.ModelForm`, define in it email/password fields with `required=False` and check both fields in `clean()` method.

Something like this:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        if not (email and password):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                             'email and password fields cannot be left blank')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = User(email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: overriding fields will also override their max_length parameters. It's better to change them in `__init__` method:

            super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs);
            self.fields['email'].required = False;
            self.fields['password'].required = False

Comment: If you are using django 1.7 then using self.add_error is better. E.g.: `self.add_error(ValidationError(u'Email and password fields cannot be left blank', code='blank-fields'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [`Model.clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) for your model

```
class MyCustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    usermail = models.EMailField(.......)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.usermail and not self.password:
            raise ValidationError({'usermail': 'Mail address and Password are required!'})
```

This will raise a validation error pointing your `usermail` field.

Comment: This will not work - usermail/password are required in `UserCreationForm` so "this field is required" exception will be thrown for them.